# Index/Update data in elasticsearch using NEST in same call

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am indexing metadata in ElasticSearch using NEST. I want to update metadata if it is already present. Does NEST has any API's to index data and update if the data is present?

How do we handle this?

Comment: What about this one https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/update-doc.html ?

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the upsert functionality within the update API.

On NEST: http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/update.html
And on ES: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts

From the NEST example:

```
client.Update<ElasticsearchProject, object>(u => u
    .Id(1)
    .Doc(new { Country = "United States"})
    .Upsert(new ElasticsearchProject { Id = 1, Country = "United States" })
);
```